# How to use eshell's `ls -I` (`ls --ignore`) option?

Tags: emacs, eshell

Since i do not want to see some of files, i tried to use **eshell**'s `ls -I` or `ls --ignore` option.

I first thought that it might behave like GNU `ls --hide` option but it's not.

It looks that **eshell ls** does not accept additional parameter.

Can someone show how to use it?

Comment: Type `$ ls --help`. `ls --ignore="i*"` works for me.

Comment: I am using emacs 24.4.1. The response was "ls: unrecognized option `--ignore="i*"`

Comment: Try `which ls` to see which `ls` you're getting.

Comment: it's exactly eshell native command

Answer (score 1):

Eshell's builtin `ls` is a lisp function, you can check that via

```
which ls
eshell/ls is a compiled Lisp function in ‘em-ls.el’
```

in your `*eshell*` buffer.

And `eshell`'s builtin `ls` supports `-I` or `--ignore` option exactly, you can check that via

```
ls --help
```

in your `*eshell*` buffer.

Finally, the `-I` or `--ignore` option of Eshell's builtin `ls` command has the same effect with GNU's `ls`.

But, it's wrong way to using **eshell's** `ls` such this:

```
ls --ignore="<pattern>"
ls -I"<pattern>"
```

The right way is:

```
ls --ignore "<pattern>"
ls --ignore "<pattern1>" --ignore "<pattern2>"
```

The reason that **eshell**'s `ls --ignore` had no effect with GNU one, because:

> If an unrecognized option is passed to this command, the external
>   version ‘/bin/ls’ will be called instead.

and `--ignore` or `--hide` had not been supported yet by the `ls` of BSD.

Comment: Yes. It's fixed(emacs 26.3 now). Thanks.